# Delete post when certain amount of reports Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

Is there a way to delete a post when it has a certain amount of reports? I store the posts in the posts collection like so:

```
posts:
|- postId:
     |- caption: String
     |- creationDate: date
     |- imageUrl: https://.....
     |- reports: Int
```

My users can report a post and that sets a +1 to the reports Int. Let's say, two people have reported the post, the reports is then `reports: 2`. I want a post to automatically be deleted once it hits a certain amount of reports. Is there a way to do so? Maybe even within Firebase?

Comment: I don't quite understand your explanation, but which one are you going to delete?

Answer (score 1):

Try an [`.onWrite()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) [Firebase RTDB trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).

This will be triggered when a given key prefix updates. You can then take action to carry out the delete, or not, each time your trigger is called.

Note: you don't want to try to do a delete on a `delete` event, so `.onWrite()` should be the correct event to listen to.